# Selecting group of children with all the same element tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains four paragraph tags. When the page is loaded, I wanted to have the first two paragraphs to be shown then have the follow paragraph elements be hidden, but I have no idea how to do this. For simplicity I set the event to a button versus a document ready event in the jsfiddle example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/zTCFe/4/

```
<div id="div">
<p>1 keep me shown</p>
<p>2 keep me shown</p>
<p>3 hide me</p>
<p>4 hide me</p>
</div>

<input type="button" value="press" id="button"/>

<script>

$('#button').click(function () {

$('#div').children().hide();

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there:

`$('#div').children(':gt(1)').hide();`

More on the [:gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/Tdue6/1/

Comment: Gromer, thanks for the help and link. You beat everyone else by about 20 seconds.

Comment: But, what happens if he wants to hide non-contiguous child nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [:gt() selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to select them

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:gt()` selector:

```
$("#div p:gt(1)").hide();
```

Or, you can also use `.slice()` to select specific elements from the jQuery object's DOM array:

```
$("#div p").slice(2).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also use .slice()

```
$('#div').children().slice(2).hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use CSS for this

```
li:nth-child(-1n+2) {
    background: yellow;
}
```